# Query mysql and run a script for each member. (BIG DATABASE)

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a fairly large database of ~800,000 members

I want to run a query on the database and run a script for each member.

How can I do that without timing out?

This isn't working for me:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM members';

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//script

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_time_limit(0)` which means there is no timelimit on the file being run.

See [`set_time_limit($seconds)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

The other risk you run is memory issues. You can raise the memory limit, but you are better off processing the data in chunks, using limits to prevent loading too much data at once.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$start = 0;
$size = 100;
while(true) {
    $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM members LIMIT %d,%d', $start, $size);

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        break;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //script

    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    $start += $size;
}
```

Comment: what if my hosting provider doesn't allow such a thing?

Comment: I don't believe this can be prevented, unless php is running in safe mode, which has been deprecated as of 5.3

Comment: how would I go about only loading say 100 members at a time?

Comment: @AndrewFerrara added an example to the answer.